# Script does not send referenced cell content

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having a big headache.
I have a sheet called Returns and through an auxiliary sheet where the data is imported, allows you to select by return code and one of the lots that are within that return (each return can have one or X lots).
After selecting both data, some cells are loaded with the relevant data to send an email notification.
So far so good, it worked the first time.

Therefore, now I needed to do exactly the same, but with another table, so I duplicated the sheet, created an auxiliary sheet equal to the first one but with the data from another table. Everything exactly the same.
THE PROBLEM: it does not send the body of the message. It sends the correct Subject, to the correct contacts, but in the message body it says #N/A.
I tried to change the definition of the ranges, to indicate it by coordinates... but nothing.
Finally it occurred to me to trim the message (removing references) until it was sent.
The message is sent as long as it does not indicate a cell containing a VLOOKUP.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S5mY.png)
If I compose the message with references to A2, B2 works correctly and sends it.
But as soon as I want to add what it says in C2 up to F2, then the message is sent as #N/A.

As you can see, row 2 of columns C:F contains a formula like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&B2;ImportRelease!C:G;4;0)
```

What blows my mind is that it finds the value as shown in the table, and the message correctly composes it with the values of those cells....
It just sends it as #N/A, and if I don't reference any of those cells C through F (but A or B), it sends it correct.

Does anyone have any idea or intuition what is going on?

I really appreciate the help because it is driving me crazy. As I say, I have another sheet exactly the same as where I duplicated this one from, and that one works perfectly.

Thank you very much in advance for the help

I'm trying to solve this problem, someone to help me or explain me the reason of the error.